# JQuery DataTable UK Date Sort Not Working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, sorting, datatables

Banging my head against the wall with this one. As the question title suggests, I have a JQuery Datatable within my MVC Razor View. One of the columns displays a Uk Date (dd/mm/yyyy) and I would like to sort this column based on it's UK Date.

I have the following within my Razor View

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
                "date-uk-pre": function (a) {
                    var ukDatea = a.split('/');
                    return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
                },

                "date-uk-asc": function (a, b) {
                    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
                },

                "date-uk-desc": function (a, b) {
                    return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
                }
            });


            $('#example').dataTable({
                stateSave: true,
                "aoColumnDefs" : [
                       {"aTargets" : [1] , "sType" : "uk_date"}
                    ]
            });


        });
</script>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="cdates" id="example">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>    
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Applicants</th>   
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var cd in Model)
        {
            <tr>
            <td><strong>@cd.CourseName</strong></td>
            <td>@cd.CourseDate</td>
            <td>@cd.CourseStatus</td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("View Applicants", "CDApps", "Portfolio", new { @id = @cd.CourseDateID, @CourseID=@cd.CourseID }, null)</td>
            </tr>             
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But still my date sort does not work. I've looked at the other similar questions on Stack Overflow but I still can't get this working.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this : replace`sType` value from `uk_date` to `date-uk` as in your sort function you are using `"date-uk-pre"`, `"date-uk-asc"` and `"date-uk-desc"`

```
$('#example').dataTable({
      stateSave: true,
      "aoColumnDefs" : [
           {"aTargets" : [1], "sType" : "date-uk"}
         ]
    });
```

And your date column has time include in date value, this is causing problem for sorting.

There are below two solutions

1) make changes in sort function to exclude time factor

```
"date-uk-pre": function (a) { 
            var ukDatea = a.split('/');
            var yearWithoutTimeValue = ukDatea[2].split(" ")[0];
            return (yearWithoutTimeValue  + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
  },
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9kg9fyv8/13/)**

2) remove time from table column values like

```
<tr>
   <td><strong>Electroconvulsive Therapy (ECT) (3 days)</strong></td>
   <td>01/05/2014</td>
   <td></td>
   <td><a href="/Portfolio/CDApps/15454?CourseID=51">View Applicants</a></td>
</tr>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9kg9fyv8/12/)**

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. It actually removed sorting from all the columns with your answer.

Comment: I tried your other answer, and the sorting is back, but the date column still isn't sorting properly. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I got the problem, first you need to correct `sType` and then either sort function or date value without time. Please check.

Comment: Fantastic. I've had alot of trouble with this in the past, but now thanks to your help I know why.